# wpf convert some xaml to c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

E
I received a good answer at the following link, I need to code this though, as I don't have a set value for the number of ellipses. I'm having a hard time converting it to c# and was hoping for some help. The answer was at [Start storyboard on a different control on a trigger in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222144/wpf-start-storyboard-on-a-different-control-on-trigger/6222286#6222286).

The code:

```xml
<Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" Name="ellipse2">
    <Ellipse.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=ellipse1}" Value="0.5">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <!-- Storyboard for ellipse 2 here -->
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the resulting effect to be? A series of ellipses that face one after another? Or pairs of ellipses, where the second always reacts on the first? Or something entirely different?

Comment: the first will be manually started, the 2nd will start at a point based on the first ellipse, the 3rd will start at a point based on the 2nd and so on, theres more to it than that, but that will be enough to get me going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(Ellipse));
var trigger = new DataTrigger();
trigger.Binding = new Binding("Opacity") { ElementName = "ellipse1" };
trigger.Value = 0.5;
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

//Add animation to sb, note the attached storyboard properties which are set with static methods:
//Storyboard.SetTarget(...);
//Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(...);
//Storyboard.SetTargetName(...);

trigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sb });
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```